# How to make backtrace()/backtrace_symbols() print the function names?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, backtrace

The Linux specific `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` allows you to produce a call trace of the program. However, it only prints function addresses, not their names for my program. How can I make them print the function names as well ? I've tried compiling the program with `-g` as well as `-ggdb`. The test case below just prints this:

```
    BACKTRACE ------------
    ./a.out() [0x8048616]
    ./a.out() [0x8048623]
    /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x4a937413]
    ./a.out() [0x8048421]
    ----------------------
```

I'd want the first 2 items to also show the function names, `foo` and `main`

Code:

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void full_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
        while (len > 0) {
                ssize_t ret = write(fd, buf, len);

                if ((ret == -1) && (errno != EINTR))
                        break;

                buf += (size_t) ret;
                len -= (size_t) ret;
        }
}

void print_backtrace(void)
{
        static const char start[] = "BACKTRACE ------------\n";
        static const char end[] = "----------------------\n";

        void *bt[1024];
        int bt_size;
        char **bt_syms;
        int i;

        bt_size = backtrace(bt, 1024);
        bt_syms = backtrace_symbols(bt, bt_size);
        full_write(STDERR_FILENO, start, strlen(start));
        for (i = 1; i < bt_size; i++) {
                size_t len = strlen(bt_syms[i]);
                full_write(STDERR_FILENO, bt_syms[i], len);
                full_write(STDERR_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        }
        full_write(STDERR_FILENO, end, strlen(end));
    free(bt_syms);
}
void foo()
{
    print_backtrace();
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get more detailed backtrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945775/how-to-get-more-detailed-backtrace)

Comment: btw, function `backtrace_symbols_fd` performs the same operation as `backtrace_symbols()`, but the resulting strings are immediately written to
     the file descriptor `fd`.

Comment: I have tested several methods in detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c/54365144#54365144

Comment: Since the second argument of backtrace() specifies the maximum number of addresses that can be stored  in  the buffer specified by the first (man 3 backtrace), a value of 1024 is unnecessarily generous here. A value of 20 should do fine, and printing a warning for possible truncation when bt_size == 20 is good practice.

Comment: This is happening with golang 1.21. I solved it by downgrading it to 1.20.8

Answer (score 78):

The symbols are taken from the dynamic symbol table; you need the `-rdynamic` option to `gcc`, which makes it pass a flag to the linker which ensures that *all* symbols are placed in the table.

(See the [Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) page of the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), and / or the [Backtraces](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) page of the [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/).)

Comment: This doesn't work for static symbols, though.  `libunwind` that @Nemo mentions, works for static functions.

Comment: In a CMake project, this had mistakenly been set as `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(-rdynamic)`.  Instead, it needs to be `ADD_LINK_OPTIONS(-rdynamic)` or equivalent to have the desired behaviour.

Comment: Better yet for those using cmake:  `SET (CMAKE_ENABLE_EXPORTS TRUE)`. This sets the -rdynamic linker flag.

Answer (score 35):

Use the [addr2line command](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html) to map executable addresses to source code filename+line number.  Give the `-f` option to get function names as well.

Alternatively, try [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/).

Comment: addr2 line is nice because it includes file name and line number in the output, but it fails as soon as relocations are performed by the loader.

Comment: ... and with ASLR relocations are more common than ever.

Comment: @ErwanLegrand: Before ASLR, I thought the relocations were predictable and `addr2line` worked reliably even for addresses in shared objects (?) But yeah, on modern platforms you would need to know the actual load address of the relocatable object even to do this operation in principle.

Comment: I can't tell for sure how well it worked before ASLR. Nowadays, it will only for for code inside "regular" executables and fail for code inside DSOs and PIEs (Position Independent Executables). Fortunately, libunwind appears to work for all of these.

Comment: I had forgotten about this discussion. Libbacktrace, which I did not know of at the time, is a better option. (See my new answer.)

Answer (score 15):

The excellent Libbacktrace by Ian Lance Taylor solves this issue. It handles stack unwinding and supports both ordinary ELF symbols and DWARF debugging symbols.

Libbacktrace does not require exporting all symbols, which would be ugly, and ASLR does not break it.

Libbacktrace was originally part of the GCC distribution. Now, a standalone version can be found on Github:

https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace

Answer (score 2):

the answer on the top has a bug
if ret == -1 and errno is EINTER you should try again, but not count ret as copied
(not going to make an account just for this, if you don't like it tough)

```
static void full_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
        while (len > 0) {
                ssize_t ret = write(fd, buf, len);

                if ((ret == -1) {
                        if (errno != EINTR))
                                break;
                        //else
                        continue;
                }
                buf += (size_t) ret;
                len -= (size_t) ret;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Boost backtrace**

Very convenient because it prints both:

- unmangled C++ function names
- line numbers

automatically for you.

Usage summary:

```
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << std::endl;
```

I have provided a minimal runnable example for it and many other methods at: [print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c/54365144#54365144)

Comment: The question is tagged [c], not [c++].