# How to get backtrace information from exception in googletest?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gdb, googletest

I'm trying to do some semi test driven design, and occasionally when I implement a new feature, it will have an exception somewhere.  All gtest tells me is what the exception is, and does not give me any backtrace information.

If I run gdb --args  --gtest_catch_exceptions=0, it will stop at the test with the exception but not have any backtrace information.  It simply states:

```
[ RUN      ] TESTNAME.test_case
EXCEPTION: exception description[Inferior 1 (process 30528) exited with code 0377]
(gdb) bt
No stack.
```

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbols? Have you tried disabling inlining to see if it cleans up a stack trace?

Answer (score 12):

Use `catch throw` gdb command to set special breakpoint before your exception is thrown. When it is hit you can see backtrace as usual by command `bt`. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html.

Answer (score 3):

In a more automatic way, you can [add your own listener](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md) and then combine the output of failing test-cases by printing additionally the backtrace using [How to make backtrace()/backtrace_symbols() print the function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934659/how-to-make-backtrace-backtrace-symbols-print-the-function-names)

Comment: first link broken

Comment: @sandwood fixed.

Comment: first link is broken again. It is here now: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md