# Is there an option to print stacktrace when test fails in GTEST on GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stack-trace, googletest

I use GTEST with GCC on Linux. I want to see stacktrace printed on test fail (be it assert or signal based crash). It can be done [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes), yet I wonder if it can be set as GTEST build/run option (without more than one line modifications to my codebase)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26583406/6394138

Answer (score 2):

There is not "fully" documented option: `--gtest_stack_trace_depth=10` (10 is just example value).

It must be used with `--gmock_verbose=info`

And yes - it works for failing `EXPECT_CALL` - in gmock only.

For asserts (like ASSERT_EQ) it has less sence - since ASSERT is just where it is - its tack trace is empty (meaning does not contain any of non-gtest/UT code).

An example:

`some_test --gmock_verbose=info --gtest_stack_trace_depth=10`

---

If you believe it shall work also for ASSERT* - you might raise an issue here: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues

Comment: Does not work for me: for running `./build/tests --gtest_stack_trace_depth=10 --gmock_verbose=info` I'm getting an assert in my code, but no stacktrace.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I mentioned in my answer - raise any complaints here: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues  I am not maintainer of gmock/gtest so I cannot help more than what is already in my answer

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, you meant it doesn't work with `ASSERT`s defined by GTest, whereas I meant a plain C/C++ `assert()` function. Anyway, to report an issue I have to have a clear source which says that the option supposed to make GTest to print a stacktrace on crash, so I could report "look, it doesn't work as documented". And I didn't find any. How did you find that it's supposed to work?