# Find what line threw an exception when running gtest

Tags: googletest

In the example below I'm running a gtest test.
An exception is thrown, but it doesn't say from what source line.
How can I get this information?

[image]

Comment: Pretty much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581066/how-to-get-backtrace-information-from-exception-in-googletest/26583406  - but answers are only half-satisfactory there