# How Do I use The -rdynamic Linker Flag?

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, backtrace

How can I use the `-rdynamic` flag to ensure glibc's backtrace functions will report the actual function/symbol names in a backtrace?

I'm trying to use [C's backtrace functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934659/how-to-make-backtrace-backtrace-symbols-print-the-function-names) to create a backtrace.  On my MacOS machine, if I use the program [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934659/how-to-make-backtrace-backtrace-symbols-print-the-function-names)

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void full_write(int fd, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
        while (len > 0) {
                ssize_t ret = write(fd, buf, len);

                if ((ret == -1) && (errno != EINTR))
                        break;

                buf += (size_t) ret;
                len -= (size_t) ret;
        }
}

void print_backtrace(void)
{
        static const char start[] = "BACKTRACE ------------\n";
        static const char end[] = "----------------------\n";

        void *bt[1024];
        int bt_size;
        char **bt_syms;
        int i;

        bt_size = backtrace(bt, 1024);
        bt_syms = backtrace_symbols(bt, bt_size);
        full_write(STDERR_FILENO, start, strlen(start));
        for (i = 1; i < bt_size; i++) {
                size_t len = strlen(bt_syms[i]);
                full_write(STDERR_FILENO, bt_syms[i], len);
                full_write(STDERR_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        }
        full_write(STDERR_FILENO, end, strlen(end));
    free(bt_syms);
}
void foo()
{
    print_backtrace();
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

and then compile it, I end up with a program that outputs a stack trace including function names.

```
$ clang main.c 
$ ./a.out 
BACKTRACE ------------
1   a.out                               0x0000000100c9fec9 foo + 9
2   a.out                               0x0000000100c9fee4 main + 20
3   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9669f235 start + 1
----------------------
```

However, if I attempt to compile the program on an Ubuntu virtual machine using gcc, I get no function names.

```
$ gcc-5 main.c 
$ ./a.out 
BACKTRACE ------------
./a.out() [0x4008c3]
./a.out() [0x4008d4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fbc9fee2830]
./a.out() [0x400649]
----------------------
```

The aformentioned previous question says the [-rdynamic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) flag is my savior, but when I try that flag I still don't get function names in my backtrace

```
$ gcc-5 -rdynamic main.c
$ ./a.out 
BACKTRACE ------------
./a.out(foo+0x9) [0x400b63]
./a.out(main+0xe) [0x400b74]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f8cbbf20830]
./a.out(_start+0x29) [0x4008e9]
```

I'm a little overwhelmed at what to do next -- am I using the flag wrong?  Or am I using it correctly and there's something else that might prevent the symbols from showing up in this simple program.

Comment: symbol names are looked up in debug sections of the executable. So, you need to allow some '-g' flag, like '-g2'. Also, you might want to turn off optimizations with '-O0'

Comment: The stack trace you showed _does_ have function names in it.  See where it says `a.out(foo+0x9)`? `foo` is the function name.  There is one on each line of the trace.

Comment: @zwol Ahem -- please pardon me while I firmly palm my face. the different format of the backtrace (from what MacOS/clang produced) tricked me. Thank you for pointing out the obvious.  Happy to mark that as the accepted answer if it's a real answer.  Otherwise I'll add the answer myself (tagging you) later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments above, the `-rdynamic` flag was working without issue.  The problem was that clang on MacOS produced its output in a different format than GCC on my ubuntu VM.

The function name was there all along.

```
# notice the function name `foo`
./a.out(foo+0x9) [0x400b63]
```

Comment: Ha!  My favorite type of problem:  The non-problem.  :)

Comment: In addition to using `-rdynamic`, also check that your build system doesn't add `-fvisibility=hidden` option! (as it will completely  discard the effect of `-rdynamic`)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) (which is also part of recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) for your backtracing goals. It wants the libraries and executables to be compiled with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) information (so you compile with `-g` passed to `gcc`, and that can be mixed with optimization flags like `-O2`). But it gives more precise output (including line numbers for your call stack frames).