# backtrace_symbols() with both -static and -rdynamic

Tags: c++, c, symbols, static-linking, backtrace

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934659/how-to-make-backtrace-backtrace-symbols-print-the-function-names) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945775/how-to-get-more-detailed-backtrace) I can see that for `backtrace_symbols()` to work, one must compile with the `-rdynamic` flag.

I've tried it into a test program and it works, but I'm writing a program that is also compiled with `-static` and [this page](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/backtrace.html) says that `backtrace_symbols()` doesn't work when `-static` is passed to the compiler/linker.

Is there any quick workaround to this or I'll never have a human-readable backtrace function in my statically linked program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was already at hand: it was in [the same page I linked in the question](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/backtrace.html). At the end, I successfully used `libunwind`.

```
#include <libunwind.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void do_backtrace()
{
    unw_cursor_t    cursor;
    unw_context_t   context;

    unw_getcontext(&context);
    unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);

    while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0)
    {
        unw_word_t  offset, pc;
        char        fname[64];

        unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &pc);

        fname[0] = '\0';
        (void) unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, fname, sizeof(fname), &offset);

        printf ("%p : (%s+0x%x) [%p]\n", pc, fname, offset, pc);
    }
}

int main()
{
 do_backtrace();
 return 0;
}
```

I was getting linking errors because I was (again) forgotting to place linker options at the end of the command line. I really don't understand why `g++`/`gcc` don't issue at least a warning when ignoring command line options. The correct command line to compile is (`-g` isn't needed):

```
g++ -static unwind.cpp -o unwind -lunwind -lunwind-x86
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely have to compile your program as static, you can still use `backtrace()` to find out addresses of the functions and then find function names by parsing debug information, using [libdwarf](http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html), for example.

But it isn't a simple task, so I'd suggest to use `-rdynamic` flag.

Comment: Yes, `-static` is mandatory in my program. I also tried with `libunwind` but my example programs don't link both on Ubuntu 12.04 x86 and x86_64. I'm always getting linking errors such as: `undefined reference to _Ux86_init_local`
`undefined reference to _Ux86_get_reg`
`undefined reference to _Ux86_get_proc_name`
`undefined reference to _Ux86_step` both with binary Ubuntu libunwind and latest self-compiled libunwind downloaded from [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/libunwind/).

Comment: @Avio I have mentioned `libdwarf`, not the `libunwind`. I had no problems linking with `libunwind`

Comment: I'll try `libdwarf` as soon as possible. I was just mentioning `libunwind` because it could be another interesting alternative without any special requirement. What architecture/distribution did you use whan you successfully linked to `libunwind`?

Comment: @Avio I am using OpenSUSE 10.x-12.x on X86 but I don't think it really matters as you can compile `libdwarf` on your platform. You would also need to link to `libelf` to be able to process ELF binary.