# Make a checksum of the current stack

Tags: c, stack, checksum

I would like to make a checksum of the current stack in the main, in order to check if it has been altered between two points.

For example:

```
int main(void) {
    ...
    stack_checksum();

    ... process ...

    if(stack_checksum() != ...)
        altered.
}
```

How can I grab the base stack address and the current address of the stack's top ?

**EDIT:** 
With @Miroslav Bajtoš help, step for *approach*:

- Put local variable in a structure
- Check backtrace return array

Comment: Despite the fact it's only main, I dare say it will be platform dependent. You may benefit from studying the way variable argument lists are handled. Check out `stdarg.h` on your platform.

Comment: @StoryTeller The variable argument list is probably implemented with `__builtin_va_list`, `__builtin_va_arg()`, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which compiler/implementation of standard library you are using.

For gcc (or any other compiler that uses glibc), you can use `backtrace()` functions in `execinfo.h` - see these answers for more details: [How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes) and [How to get more detailed backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945775/how-to-get-more-detailed-backtrace)

For Microsoft compiler, you can use `StackWalk64()` function, see this article for more details: [Walking-the-callstack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack). There was also a similar quesion asked here on StackOverflow: [StackWalk64 on Windows - Get symbol name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705650/stackwalk64-on-windows-get-symbol-name)

Computing checksum should be easy once you can walk the stack.

Comment: The array returned by backtrace contains stack and code segments address, no ? I get the main addres (0x8048...), etc. but not the stack address, no ?

Comment: Yes, you have a complete stack of called functions (including the code segment address, as you pointed out). Did you want to read something else instead?

Comment: If it's possible to get the address of the base pointer and the stack length, it will be easy to checksum it. I guess that called functions address will not help. The answer of @Cooday seems good but need asm inline.

Comment: @Maxux OK, why do you want to checksum the stack in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? Verifying that local variables has same values?

Comment: Overall, yes. In fact it's to check if the process (cf code on original post) don't alter the stack (overflow, ...).

Comment: Well, if you want to check variable values, then maybe you can put them in a custom structure and then you can compute hash of this structure. BTW, comparing variables on the stack won't be very reliable. Think about **argv parameter of main: argv value stays still the same even if value of argv[0] was modified.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to use inline assembly for this. The following code stores the current values of the base pointer and the current pointer in `base` and `current`. It's for `gcc` on a 64-bit machine:

```
// make these variables global (if not, the stack registers would change)
void *base, *current;
__asm__("movq %%rbp, %0;"
        "movq %%rsp, %1;"
        : "=r"(base), "=r"(current)
        :
        :
);
```

If you are on a 32-bit machine you have to use `ebp` and `esp` instead of `rbp` and `rsp` and `movl` instead of `movq`.
I recommend you to check out [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) inline assembly tutorial for gcc if you have any questions with the syntax.

Comment: I already thought of that, I was looking for a way to do it without inline asm.